# How do you make a pie chart for each group in a report?

Tags: sql, ms-access, graph, charts

I have a report which contains a detail section and a group footer. In each group footer I would like to insert a pie chart that shows information for the current group. I have managed to insert the pie chart but it shows the data for the whole report rather than just the current group. How can I make the pie chart only show the data for the current group?

[image: Report Data Source]

[image: Report Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Access 2010 and can only use classic MSGraph chart, not ModernChart.

Put textbox bound to Custodian field in Custodian header or footer section and name it tbxCustodian.

Set chart RowSource to:

`SELECT Currency, Sum(Value) AS SumVal FROM Data GROUP BY Currency HAVING Custodian = [tbxCustodian];`